# Loop limit in animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to make a sound visualizer.

I want to use a loop to apply transformations on objects in a group.

I make a loop. Plug the Goup node to it. There are 1313 cubes in this group.

It's my first time using the Group node so as a test I use the Object Output node and set the scale to .2 inside my loop

Only 10 objects receive the transformation. If I use Debug List I see that those are the first 10 objects in the group. If I use a Debug node on Interations in my loop it outputs 10.

Could this be a memory issue? Does Animation Nodes stop at 10 when memory is not enough?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is **no limit to the number of iterations** in theory.

What makes your loop a bit more advanced is that you iterate through two lists at the same time. Normally you only want to do this when both lists have the same length because the addon works in the following way:

At first the loop will take the first element from both lists (Index 0). Then the second element from both lists, etc... This will continue until it reaches the last element of a list -> so **the shortest list defines the number of iterations in a loop**. The rest will be ignored.

The *Evaluate Sound* node outputs a float list with 10 elements in your example.

[image]

The debug node in a loop always shows the last value that went into the node.

If you just want to move around all the objects you can simply remove the Float Iterator from the loop. Then each object should receive the transformation.

I guess you want to use the sound information in the loop with a different frequency for each object. The easiest way to archieve this is to use the Sound Equalizer template that ships with the addon:

[image]

Comment: Nice! THE Jacques Lucke answered. Thanks for your work and answer.


I want to use equalizer data so I built a similar node tree but instead of using Index/Iterations as the factor for the Mix Float List I used the distance to an empty, because I want to make a radial visualization. 

Ergo, near the empty the cubes move following the lower frequencies, away from the empty they follow higher frequencies.